# How to keep shared borders in the attributes table of multiple polylines

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

I have a shapefile of polygons for the countries in Africa. I want to turn them to polylines so I just have the country borders, and then when I look at the border for a given country, I want to have the whole border be attributed to a country rather than just a section.

For example, the border between Egypt and Libya. The two countries border each other, but when I turn the polygon to a polyline the shared border is only attributed to Egypt in the attributes table, and I want to have the border also be counted for Libya as well.

Is there a way to attribute that shared border to both countries, and is there a way to generalize this in QGIS (or any GIS software for that matter?) My end goal is to run some analysis with 1000s of polygons that aren't country borders, but thought if I could figure it out for this case I can apply it to my specific cases after.

Comment: Use two attributes, one for the left side country and another for the right side country. You must split the line into segments for getting the neighbor countries right for each segment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure to have well understood what you are trying to do here but I guess you shall have a look at the "join attributes by location" tool or the intersection tool:

-input layer: polylines

-intersect layer: Africa shapefile

Once you will have run the tool you will get a new polyline layer where every polyline features will be duplicated based on the number of countries it touches.

The polyline feature associated with Niger for instance would be duplicated 5 times:
1 associated to Chad; 1 to Nigeria, 1 to Burkina faso, 1 to Algeria, 1 to Libya.